# Executing adb shell from PHP and escaping strings

Tags: php, adb

I am trying to convert a working bash script into PHP code.

```
#!/bin/bash
phonenumber="$1"
message="$2"

# check the args...
# double quotes inside $message must be escaped. Also prevents code injection.
message=${message//\"/\\\"}

adb shell "am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e \"contact\" $phonenumber -e msg \"$message\""
```

The code above works.
In PHP, next code doesn't work when the messages includes a new line:

```
function sendsms ($m, $to, $n) {
    echo "About to sent an sms to $to [$n]\n";

    // escape some chars in $m
    $m = addslashes($m);

    adb_shell_exec ("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact \"$to\" -e msg \"$m\"");

}

function adb_shell_exec ($s) {
    shell_exec("adb shell " . addslashes ($s));
}
```

I get the message error:

```
       $ php -r "require 'sim-android-v8.php'; sendsms('Message with one double \" quote final solution
       and new line','+32*******31','Pierre François');"
       About to sent an sms to +32*******31 [Pierre François]
       /system/bin/sh: no closing quote
       sh: 2: and: not found
```

I don't understand why it works in bash but not in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to FAEWZX, I discovered the proper use of the function **escapeshellarg()**. The answer he gave above is working in most of the cases, but is not waterproof. IMO, the code below is better because it covers 100% of the cases so far, using **escapeshellarg()** twice and recursively.

```
function sendsms ($m, $to, $n) {
    echo "About to sent an sms to $to [$n]\n";

    $subshell = 'am startservice --user 0' .
      ' -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS' .
      ' -e contact ' . escapeshellarg($to) . 
      ' -e msg ' . escapeshellarg($m);

    $shell = 'adb shell ' . escapeshellarg($subshell);

    shell_exec($shell);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same bash script

```
function sendsms ($m, $to, $n) {
echo "About to sent an sms to $to [$n]\n";

$m = escapeshellarg(addslashes($m)); // use escape for shell
$to = escapeshellarg($to);
// double quotes around command for sub shell
shell_exec('adb shell "am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact '.$to.' -e msg '.$m.'"');
}
```

Comment: Great FAEWZX, you made my day. It works. I only have one problem: if the message contains a single quote ('), the output includes a backslash (\\) before it. This is due to the function addslashes that adds a backslash not only before the double quotes (") but also the single ones ('). However, this is not critical, the code is working.

Comment: See another solution below.