# How to parse string for send SMS text message via ADB

Tags: php, parsing, sms, adb, message

Im trying to send SMS via ADB terminal command.

```
$message = "Joe Doe. We find a provider for your request, touch the link below for see more details.
https://massasistencia.com/detalles-cliente/23"

exec('adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409605" s16 "null" s16 "' .$message. '" s16 "null" s16 "null"')
```

The message recived says only "Joe"

If i send only the link the SMS arrives ok.
If i do a str_replace to "Joe Doe" replacing " " for "-" only sending the name, the message arrives ok.

I believe the problem is the spaces " ".

This is the command line im using, the SMS arrives, so the command works, the problem is the message itself.

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409958" s16 "null" s16 "Hi" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

Comment: Maybe try escaping your whitespace? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683077/adb-command-fail-to-execute-if-path-contain-spaces and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: spaces should be fine can you hard code the msg in the string just to test `exec('adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409605" s16 "null" s16 "Joe Doe. We find a provider" s16 "null" s16 "null"')`

Comment: Since it's two shells involved, double escapeshellarg perhaps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing adb shell from PHP and escaping strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792237/executing-adb-shell-from-php-and-escaping-strings)

Comment: @miken32 Nice! Yeah, messaging little `Bobby Rm -rf` is another reason to escape properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **slash character** (\) before each space character in the message.
The following command will only send Joe:

```
 adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409958" s16 "null" s16 "Joe Doe. hello" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

The following command will send Joe Doe. hello:

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409958" s16 "null" s16 "Joe\ Doe.\ hello" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

Comment: what about new lines?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a slash character () before each space character in the message.
isn't it thug life work ??
try to enclose your SMS body in single quotes and you are all done.

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+541156409958" s16 "null" s16 "'Joe Doe. hello'" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```